# Pipe output from script as argument into next command

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script

I'm trying to get information from a perl script piped to the next command to use in a **docker** script (so it needs to execute in a single pipeline). For some reason, the stdout from the command is not working correctly.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
# perl -e '($prefix) = `nginx -V 2>&1` =~ /configure arguments: (.*)/; print $prefix;' | ../configure $(</dev/stdin) --add-dynamic-module=nginx-upload-module-master
```

If I try to echo out, the stdin from the first command, then it produces no output.

```
# perl -e '($prefix) = `nginx -V 2>&1` =~ /configure arguments: (.*)/; print $prefix;' | echo $(</dev/stdin)

#
```

Any idea why this is not working as I would suspect? I am using the dash shell.

p.s.  I know the first command is working correctly:

```
# perl -e '($prefix) = `nginx -V 2>&1` =~ /configure arguments: (.*)/; print $prefix;'
--with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-YlUNvj/nginx-1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dash does support `$(…)` for command substitution, but `</dev/stdin` is not a command that outputs anything. It's a sole redirection.

In Bash `$(<file)` is equivalent to `$(cat file)`, but it's a special case, a syntax supported for user's convenience. Apparently it's not supported in Dash.

If you want this `$(</dev/stdin)` itself to work in Dash like you expected, use `$(cat /dev/stdin)`. But I don't think `$(…)` is a good way in the first place. I can see the first command outputs a string containing single-quotes that should be interpreted. Quotes in the output are to protect some spaces. Command substitution does not interpret quotes. Certainly unquoted `$(cat /dev/stdin)` will split the string in wrong places, but if you [quote it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) then it will form a single argument; in any case the quotes will still be there.

The string from the first command probably should be used with `xargs` or *maybe* with `eval`. I don't know `nginx -V`, so I cannot tell for sure.

This is how you do it with `xargs`:

```
perl -e '($prefix) = `nginx -V 2>&1` =~ /configure arguments: (.*)/; print $prefix;' \
| xargs ../configure --add-dynamic-module=nginx-upload-module-master
```

`xargs` will interpret quotes and thus it will create a single argument from `--with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-YlUNvj/nginx-1.14.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'`.

Comment: # is the dash command prompt as configured on my system. Maybe I should edit for clarity?

Comment: @markf78 Are you trying to say that your `perl` command prints something that doesn't end with a newline character, so the prompt gets "glued" to the end of the output? And you posted the output with this prompt for some reason? This would explain the trailing `#`, but it's not obvious. Maybe if I knew `perl` and if your first snippet didn't contain this trailing `"`…

Comment: No, sorry, I was trying to say my command prompt itself is a "#" instead of the more common "user@host:~$" or something like that.

Comment: it's my prompt.

Comment: @markf78 So yes, your `perl` command prints something that doesn't end with a newline character, so the prompt gets "glued" to the end of the output. Sigh… What is your reason for including the prompt in this position in a snippet in your question? IMO it's quite misleading.

Comment: the output of the perl script can be found above in my "p.s." section. the first line of the section is the perl script execution and the second line is the output from it.

Comment: I'll remove it.

Comment: @markf78 "and the second line is the output from it" – And the `#` I'm talking about is at the end of *this* line. Now you're telling me the line is the output.

Comment: Please check it.

Comment: @markf78 The `#` you have just removed was in the beginning of the first line. I had no problem with it whatsoever, I was able to identify it as the prompt. There is still `#` at the end of the second line and you claim this line is the output. The output, **including the trailing `#`**, right?

Comment: I just noticed it. I'm sorry I wasnt scrolling to the right of the whole long output. now I see the confusion.

Comment: FYI, in general I find leading `#` (or `$`, or `whatever>` that looks like a *genuine* prompt) useful to indicate which line is a command and which line is its output. This discussion from my side was never about the leading `#` in your code and I did not want you to remove it from the question. If you decide to add it back, I won't oppose. If you decide to leave it without `#`, I won't oppose either.